# VB.NET Class Serialization designer error

Tags: vb.net, debugging, serialization, properties, designer

I want to make my own menu. Therefore I want to use panels for my menu body and for menu items as well.

Here is my class (in short):

```
Public Class MenuM
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Panel
    '
    Private collectionValue As List(Of MenuMItem)
    '
    Public Property Collection As List(Of MenuMItem)
        Set(value As List(Of MenuMItem))
            collectionValue = value
        End Set
        Get
            Return collectionValue
        End Get
    End Property
    '
    Public Sub New()
        Me.Collection = New List(Of MenuMItem)
    End Sub
    '
    Public Class MenuMItem
        Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Panel
    End Class
End Class
```

When I add `Me.Collection = New List(Of MenuMItem)` (is this the problem?) line in constructor I get serialization error messages both by designer and debugger:

This error I get when trying to add my class as control onto my main form:

[image: Error 1]

This one I get when trying to start debugging:

[image: Error 2]

I tried to add `<Serializable()>` above `Public Class MenuM` and `Public Class MenuMItem`. This doesn't help. I don't understand the problem. Can anyone help, please?

Thanks a lot!

---

**Is this the solution?** (hehe)

```
Imports System
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization
Imports System.Security.Permissions
Imports System.IO


<Serializable()>
Public Class MenuM
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Panel
    Implements ISerializable
    '
    Public Sub New()

    End Sub
    '
    Protected Sub New(ByVal info As SerializationInfo, _
    ByVal context As StreamingContext)
        If info Is Nothing Then
            Throw New System.ArgumentNullException("info")
        End If
        collectionValue = info.GetValue("AltMenuMItemList", GetType(List(Of MenuMItem)))
    End Sub
    '
    <SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, _
    Flags:=SecurityPermissionFlag.SerializationFormatter)> _
    Public Overridable Sub GetObjectData _
    (ByVal info As SerializationInfo, _
    ByVal context As StreamingContext) _
    Implements ISerializable.GetObjectData
        If info Is Nothing Then
            Throw New System.ArgumentNullException("info")
        End If
        info.AddValue("AltMenuMItemList", New List(Of MenuMItem))
    End Sub
    '
    Private collectionValue As List(Of MenuMItem)
    '
    Public Property Collection As List(Of MenuMItem)
        Set(value As List(Of MenuMItem))
            collectionValue = value
        End Set
        Get
            Return collectionValue
        End Get
    End Property
    '
    <Serializable()>
    Public Class MenuMItem
        Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Panel
        Implements ISerializable

        Private textValue As String
        Overloads Property Text As String
            Set(value As String)
                textValue = value
            End Set
            Get
                Return textValue
            End Get
        End Property

        <SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, _
        Flags:=SecurityPermissionFlag.SerializationFormatter)> _
        Public Sub GetObjectData(info As System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo, _
                             context As System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext) _
    Implements System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable.GetObjectData

            If info Is Nothing Then
                Throw New System.ArgumentNullException("info")
            End If
            textValue = info.GetValue("AltText", GetType(String))
        End Sub

        Protected Sub New(ByVal info As SerializationInfo, _
       ByVal context As StreamingContext)
            If info Is Nothing Then
                Throw New System.ArgumentNullException("info")
            End If
            info.AddValue("AltText", "XXX")
        End Sub

        Sub New()

        End Sub
    End Class
End Class
```

**Source:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.getobjectdata(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

Comment: Menus are slightly different animals than ordinary controls.  A Panel full of child panels is not going to work the same way.  To fix up the MenuM class use `<DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)>`.  MenuItem is beyond repair though

Comment: Because I had too many problems with panels within panels (when calling events like OnMouseEnter or onMouseWheel), I am about to make a User control as a Menu(body) with a Panel within (as container of menu items) and user controls as menu items. But I still have troubles. This time not with scrolling etc., but with designer and debugger again.

Comment: A UserControl *is* a container so the panel is not needed for that.  A UC is not a menu either though

Comment: Is this what you mean? (Property `MenuMItems` replaces `Collection`)
<DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)> _
            <Browsable(False)>
            Property MenuMItems As List(Of MenuMItem)

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing.  If Browsable is false, you cant add any menu items via the IDE Collection editor, if it has no items how do they get there?